# Verizon 4g mobile broadband not working "SIM failed"

Tags: windows-xp, mobile-broadband

I have a desktop Dell with Windows XP Professional, with the SP3. I ordered Verizon's 4G broadband mobile and installed it.

However, before it connects, a pop up window tells me "SIM failed".

Several Verizon techs offered to get a new SIM card – I did, same response; another said I needed a WiFi card or Service Pack 3 (have it). I used the same CD software program to load the 4G broadband on my laptop (Windows 7) and it was successful.

Verizon techs keep giving me the run around... did anyone have this same problem? If so, what worked to fix it?